# Convert euro sign from a PHP sent JSON string to a Java string (utf-8)

Tags: java, php, android

i am building an **Android** application that prints to a thermal printer and i have problems with printing `&euro;` symbol.

Specifically, my Android application:

- makes a **GET** request  to a php file
- the php file build a **JSON** object
- one of my JSON values contains a **"\u20AC"**, that is, euro sign in unicode.
- php file stringifies the JSON + send it back to **Android**

which sends the data **UTF-8** encoded (plain text)

My PHP sending-back code is, basically, something like that:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n");
...
$currency_symbol = '\u20AC';
...
$blah = array("id"=>$order['id'], ... , "currency_symbol"=> $currency_symbol);
echo json_encode( $blah ); 
exit;
```

Before all that, i was able to print the € sign to a printer by:

- Changing to correct code page of thermal printer
- Calling the following code:

`new String("\u20ac").getBytes( Charset.forName("Windows-1252") ) );`

then sending `euro` bytes directly to printer.

**`With JSON solution, i can not render the euro sign anymore as every try, even the previous working one, it always renders this to printer (but not the sign):`**

`\u20AC`

**PS.** I have no problem with the other UTF-8 strings as i am able to print them by that:

```
String.format("- " + json_obj.getString("address") + "\n").getBytes( charset )
```

where `json_obj` is the encoded JSON that came from PHP and charset in what code page the printer is set to (as `Charset`).

Comment: Can you give an example of a JSON that you receive from the backend? How does the euro sign look like there?

Comment: @YamashiroRion, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the following code:

```
String currency_symbol_hex = order_obj.getString("currency_symbol");
String currency_symbol_str = Character.toString((char) Integer.parseInt(currency_symbol_hex,16));
BT_write( String.format("%s", currency_symbol_str).getBytes( Charset.forName("Windows-1252") ) );
```

where `order_obj.getString("currency_symbol")` is a JSON value sent by the PHP and contains only `20AC` (rather `\u20AC`) and `BT_write` basically writes the bytes to a connected Bluetooth socket.

The `currency_symbol` is stored in JSON like that:

```
   return array(
      ...
      "euro"=>array("symbol"=>"&euro;","symbol_unicode"=>"20AC")
                                                   -------^
      ...
   );
```

and i just return it through the `currency_symbol` key in my JSON.

This is obviously not the best solution as different currencies may require different character set than `Windows-1252` and also requires special case on PHP side (sending 2 unicode codes eg. `\u0631.\u0639.` (the Omani rial currency symbol) wont work unless you use an array and parse each one etc.) but at least its a start. Thanx!